# Does glibc wcslen() expect data alignment along wchar_t sized boundaries?

Tags: c++, glibc

Been wracking my brain for hours on this one.  glibc `wcslen()` is returning a different value than expected for a given input string.  I've narrowed the problem to a possible data alignment issue but even that doesn't make sense to me.  My own function that dumps the string appears to work fine and also calculates the size similar to how `wcslen()` supposedly works.

```c
    #ifndef WCHAR
        #define WCHAR wchar_t
    #endif

...

void DumpWCStr(const WCHAR *str)
{
    size_t len = 0, len2 = wcslen(str);

    while (*str != L'\0')
    {
        printf("%lu %lc\n", (size_t)*str, *str);

        str++;
        len++;
    }

    printf("Size:  %lu (wcslen:  %lu)\n", len, len2);
}

void TestFunc()
{
    char *prebuffer = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(WCHAR) + 1);
    WCHAR *tempbuffer = (WCHAR *)(prebuffer + 1);
    WCHAR tempbuffer2[100];

    memset(prebuffer, 0xFF, 100 * sizeof(WCHAR) + 1);
    swprintf(tempbuffer, 100, L"%ls (%d)", L"test", 15);
DumpWCStr(tempbuffer);

    memset(prebuffer, 0xFF, 100 * sizeof(WCHAR) + 1);
    tempbuffer = (WCHAR *)prebuffer;
    swprintf(tempbuffer, 100, L"%ls (%d)", L"test", 15);
DumpWCStr(tempbuffer);

    memset(prebuffer, 0xFF, 100 * sizeof(WCHAR) + 1);
    swprintf(tempbuffer2, 100, L"%ls (%d)", L"test", 15);
DumpWCStr(tempbuffer2);
}
```

Outputs:

```
116 t
101 e
115 s
116 t
32
40 (
49 1
53 5
41 )
Size:  9 (wcslen:  8)
116 t
101 e
115 s
116 t
32
40 (
49 1
53 5
41 )
Size:  9 (wcslen:  9)
116 t
101 e
115 s
116 t
32
40 (
49 1
53 5
41 )
Size:  9 (wcslen:  9)
```

glibc wcslen() implementation from [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=wcsmbs/wcslen.c;h=9d94c62210797b226e6cee697f8bbf11c9d6c9eb;hb=HEAD) shows wcslen() implemented as:

```
size_t
 __wcslen (const wchar_t *s)
 {
   size_t len = 0;
 
   while (s[len] != L'\0')
     {
       if (s[++len] == L'\0')
         return len;
       if (s[++len] == L'\0')
         return len;
       if (s[++len] == L'\0')
         return len;
       ++len;
     }
 
     return len;
  }
```

Attempting to `printf("%ls\n", tempbuffer);` after the first `swprintf()` results in:

```
wcsrtombs.c:94: __wcsrtombs: Assertion `data.__outbuf[-1] == '\0'' failed.
```

Which probably happens because `__wcslen()` is returning 8 instead of 9 inside `__wcsrtombs()`.

I'm compiling the code as C++ and the target is Intel x86/x64.

So is glibc wcslen() expecting data alignment on wchar_t sized boundaries?  That's not how I read the source code for wcslen() but it certainly is acting like it expects data alignment.

Comment: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/x86_64/wcslen.S is wcslen. Now try doing `memset(tempbuffer, 0xff, sizeof(tempbuffer))` and try it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, C++ always requires that all access to an object is aligned to at least as strict boundary as the type requires. This is because objects cannot exist in misaligned addresses. So, this requirement is not specific to `wcslen`.

On your system, `alignof(wchar_t)` is likely greater than 1, in which case `prebuffer + 1` is always misaligned and therefore cannot contain a `wchar_t` object.

Violating this requirement results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you.  KamilCuk's pointer to the SSE2 assembly version was also helpful.  I have a mess to sort out now (mostly my fault for being lazy) but I understand what's going on.